# How do I change an int to a double in this code?

Tags: java, casting

I'm trying to run a program which calculates balance after interest. I easily got it to run with:

```
public class bigjavach1p7balprob{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    double balance = 10000.0;
    int year = 0;

    while (balance < 20000){
      year += 1;
      double interest = balance * .05;
      balance = balance + interest;

      System.out.println("year " + year + ": " + balance);

    }
  }
}
```

but I want to have balance as an int first, and then convert it to double when the interest is added. I have:

```
import java.util.*;

public class bigjavach1p7balprob{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    int balance = 10000;
    int year = 0;

    while (balance < 20000){
      year += 1;
      double interest = (double)balance * .05;
      balance = Integer.parseInt(balance) + interest;

      System.out.println("year " + year + ": " + balance);

    }
  }
}
```

This isn't compiling or running.

Comment: What reason do you have to want to do this?

Comment: If this is to round balance to whole dollar amount, how to you want to round? Down? Half-Up *(as we learned in school)*? Half-Even *(bankers rounding)*? Up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the compilation error is that `Integer.parseInt()` takes in a `String` not a `int`.

If you wanted to change the `balance` to a whole number (integer) you could cast it to an `int` (even if it's a `double`):

```
balance = (int) (balance + interest)
```

But you can't actually change the variable type.